# Ms-Word introduces line breaks in RTF

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007, templates, newlines, rtf

I'm using a template system based on RTF + Velocity. In my RTF's I've got several [VTL](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/vtl-reference-guide.html) sentences, such as:

```
#foreach($item in $somevar.someProp)Some may-be RTF text #end
```

If I open the RTF file with Word (2007) and apply any lesser change somewhere else in the document, I sometimes get VTL sentences broken :

```
#foreach($item in $somevar.som
eProp)Some may-be RTF text #end
```

This causes the template engine to choke on the sentence, and having to open the RTF with a text editor to restore the split line every time is quite annoying. Note this does not always happen, it seems to be specific on some files. It also doesn't have anything to do with line length, there are other lines longer than the one that gets split.

Does someone know why might Word be doing this, or how to avoid it?